# How to overload the product method of a typeclass

Tags: scala, typeclass, overloading, generic-programming, shapeless

I am trying to implement a ReadJsonCodec of sorts using the automatic type class derivation mechanism in Shapeless.

Here is my ReadCodecCompanionObject:

```
object ReadCodec extends LabelledProductTypeClassCompanion[ReadCodec] {
  implicit object StringCodec extends SimpleCodec[String] {
    def read(j: Json): String = j.stringOr(throw ...)
  }
  implicit object IntCodec ...
  implicit object BooleanCodec ...
  implicit object LongCodec ...
  implicit object ShortCodec ...
  implicit object DoubleCodec ...
  implicit object BigDecimalCodec ...

  implicit def readCodecInstance: LabelledProductTypeClass[ReadCodec] = new LabelledProductTypeClass[ReadCodec] {
    def emptyProduct = new ReadCodec[HNil] {
      // This will silently accept extra fields within a JsonObject
      // To change this behavior make sure json is a JsonObject and that it is empty
      def read(json: Json) = HNil
    }

    def product[F, T <: HList](name: String, FHead: ReadCodec[F], FTail: ReadCodec[T]) = new ReadCodec[F :: T] {
      def read(json: Json): F :: T = {
        val map = castOrThrow(json)
        val fieldValue = map.getOrElse(name, throw new MappingException(s"Expected field $name on JsonObject $map"))
        // Try reading the value of the field
        // If we get a mapping exception, intercept it and add the name of this field to the path
        // If we get another exception, don't touch!
        // Pitfall: if handle did not accept a PartialFunction, we could transform an unknow exception into a match exception
        val head: F = Try(FHead.read(fieldValue)).handle{ case MappingException(msg, path) => throw MappingException(msg, s"$name/$path")}.get
        val tail = FTail.read(json)
        head :: tail
      }
    }

    def product[A, T <: HList](name: String, FHead: ReadCodec[Option[A]], FTail: ReadCodec[T]) = new ReadCodec[Option[A] :: T] {
      def read(json: Json): Option[A] :: T = {
        val map = castOrThrow(json)
        val head: Option[A] = map.get(name).map { fieldValue =>
          Try(FHead.read(fieldValue)).handle{ case MappingException(msg, path) => throw MappingException(msg, s"$name/$path")}.get.get
        }
        val tail = FTail.read(json)
        head :: tail
      }
    }

    def project[F, G](instance: => ReadCodec[G], to : F => G, from : G => F) = new ReadCodec[F] {
      def read(json: Json): F = from(instance.read(json))
    }
  }
}
```

That's somewhat of a complicated piece of code to just grasp quickly but is really fairly simple once you understand it. The important part is the two `def product` methods. The problem I am having is that I want this codec to accept a Json AST that is missing a field if that field would be mapped to a value of type `Option[A]`. This means that I need the product function to know if the head of the HList is of type Option[A] or not.

Concretely:

```
case class Foo(a: String, b: Option[Boolean])
val test = read[Foo](json"""{"a" : "Beaver"}""") // should work
```

But currently this would fail because it makes no distinction for Option and expects a field `b`. I tried two ways of fixing this and neither of them worked.

The first one and the cleanest one is to overload the product method with a version where the F type parameter is replaced with Option[A]. This approach is fairly clean, although I am not sure whether or not it would play well with the shapeless derivation macro. However, it is not possible because Scala does not support the ability to overload functions when the type signature after erasure is the same. This is the version that is above. Unfortunately, this does not currently compile with the Scala compiler.

The second approach was to use a TypeTag to find out at runtime if F is of type Option[_] and behave appropriately. This version would almost certainly be less elegant and involve a cast but I could live with it. However, it seems impossible because the addition of a TypeTag changes the signature of the product method (adding an implicit parameter) and then the compiler complains that I am not defining the abstract method product.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to proceed.

Comment: What does your `Json` look like?

Comment: I am not convinced it's pertinent for the question, but Json is some AST representation of JSON. In my specific case this library adopts the approach of modeling Json mostly as type synonyms. So Json = Any, JsonObject = Map[String, Json] and JsonArray = List[Json]

Comment: The reliance on runtime reflection is pretty deeply at odds with the design of Shapeless. I'm not at a computer at the moment, but if you have so little static type information I'm not sure Shapeless is going to be able to help you much.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for a solution that did not rely on reflection. Although I explored the use of TypeTag, I would much prefer overloading `product`. Are you saying even by overloading product, there is still reflection in this approach?

Comment: @TravisBrown I can edit my post to use spray-json's strongly typed AST (or Argonaut) if that would help you reason about the problem. My impression is that it does not fundamentally change the problem but I might make a realization to the contrary by going through the exercise of doing this.

Comment: @TravisBrown Done, I have updated the answer to use the Argonaut AST and also just generally minimized the problem statement. Hopefully this makes my problem clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get a typeclass with information about `F` passed through. But you're already passing a typeclass around, in the form of `ReadCodec`. So the solution is to replace that with one that contains all the information you need:

```
trait ReadCodecAndTypeTag[A] {
  val rc: ReadCodec[A]
  val tt: TypeTag[A]
}
```

But in that case you might as well delegate the decoding-from-optional-value-in-a-map to this typeclass as well:

```
trait OReadCodec[A] {
  val rc: ReadCodec[A]
  def missingField(name: String, map: Any): A =
    throw new MappingException(s"Expected field $name on JsonObject $map")
}
implicit object StringCodec extends OReadCodec[String] {
  val rc = new ReadCodec[String] {...}
}
implicit object IntCodec ...
...
implicit def OptionCodec[A](implicit orc: OReadCodec[A]) =
 new OReadCodec[Option[A]] {
  val rc = ...
  override def missingField(name: String, map: Any) = None
}
...
def product[F, T <: HList](name: String, FHead: OReadCodec[F], FTail: OReadCodec[T]) =
  new OReadCodec[F :: T] {
    val rc = new ReadCodec[F :: T] {
      def read(json: Json): F :: T = {
      val map = castOrThrow(json)
      val fieldValue = map.getOrElse(name, FHead.missingField(name, map))
      val head: F = ...
      ...
    }
  }
}

implicit def ReadCodecFromOReadCodec[A](implicit orc: OReadCodec[A]) = orc.rc
```